# How to know if back/forward was pressed instead of a manual router push in vue/vue-router?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

In vue/vue-router, I have a watcher on `$route` which gets triggered in 2 ways.

1. I click back or forward on the browser.
2. the user interacts with the form, there are watchers on the variables that the form uses, and these watcher functions then update the url using `$router.push`.

So then in the watcher function for `$route`, how do I know which of the above 2 scenarios occurred?

The problem is, if scenario 1 occurred, I want to manually update the form again. If scenario 2 happened, the form will have have already been updated, so I don't want to manually update the form again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do the trick

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
  console.log("location: " + document.location + ", state: " + JSON.stringify(event.state));
};
```

it runs when I do back or forward, and not when I manually update URL.

Answer (score 0):

> So then in the watcher function for `$route`, how do I know which of the above 2 scenarios occurred?

You can't. A watcher will execute whenever the watched value changes in any way, you won't know what caused the value to change within the callback.

If you want to know when the route changes due to the user clicking back/forward browser button, you'll need to add an event listener for the [`popstate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate) event.

> The problem is, if scenario 1 occurred, I want to manually update the form again. If scenario 2 happened, the form will have have already been updated, so I don't want to manually update the form again.

I don't see an issue with updating the form on *any* change to the data in the URL params/query; you can check if the URL data is the same as the form data and skip the update.

Comment: But does the popstate event occur before the watcher event function on the `$route`?

Comment: Regarding the new comment, the URL changes in both scenarios (clicking back or forward, or user updating form) so I can't check for that. So the watcher function on $route triggers both ways.

Comment: Right, but what I'm saying is why do you even need to distinguish between them? Whenever the URL changes, *for whatever reason*, update the form. Simple as that. I've done that in the past and it worked fine.

Comment: It needs to support click back or forward as well. If I keep the logic simple as you describe, then when user updates form, it ends up refreshing the form twice.

Comment: First just by the vue reactivity, and the 2nd time, its because it also updates the url to be in sync with the form, and that again updates the form.

Comment: Why would refreshing the form twice be an issue? If the data is the same, the form won't update. And if you implement the optimization I mentioned (only updating the form if the form data is out of sync with the URL data) then it will only be updated once.

Comment: It's because there is dynamic ajax data being downloaded and there is a lot of it. So I manually have to do this on a URL change event.

Comment: I'm going to need a fiddle or something because you have lots of requirements that are specific to your issue.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: So what I want is to keep the URL and form in sync on page load and as the user updates the form. 
On click back/forward is simpler, as the url is values is the truth, so I go and update the form based on the url params.
However then as the user interacts with the form, vue's reactivity updates the view (thats view update #1). But then I want to keep the url in sync, so I do a manual router.push. This then means I need to update the form again to be in sync with the url (thats view update #2). Same code as previous sentence. This is the part I want to avoid (#2) when user updates the form.

Comment: So a simple way to avoid that extra view update, is in the URL update event in the watcher, would be to have an if statement that checks if the page was reloaded from a back/forward or if the URL updated because the user interacted with the form.

Comment: I don't understand why you need to "update the form again to be in sync with the url" – wouldn't the form and URL be in sync? User interacts with form -> form updates -> form/URL out of sync, so you update the URL to match the form. Now they're both in sync? Why is update #2 necessary? Please, provide a fiddle.

Comment: 2 reasons there, the form is not tied with the url, something needs to manually take the url values and put it in the form. And second is to update the view, there is a expensive AJAX download.

Comment: When I do a back/forward, the url changes, but the form does not, it needs to manually be refreshed.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you any further. Good luck.